# How to monitor nginx running in a docker swarm with prometheus?

Tags: docker, nginx, lua, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

Problem: Monitor Nginx
Scenario: I have a Docker swarm with 4 replicas of Nginx. I need some basic metrics such as latency, HTTP status, etc. I checked out [knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus](https://github.com/knyar/nginx-lua-prometheus). It's working fine for a single machine, which exposes an endpoint and prometheus can scrape that. But in my case nginx is running in a swarm, where if I expose a port then **docker will load balance** the request, hence the metrics won't be correct.

What is the ideal way to do monitoring of a docker swarm Nginx?

Comment: Please refer to this (long) [open issue #1766](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/1766) on github. It discussed how SD can be operated in DockerSwarm and give pointers.